# How can i draw coastlines in openmaptiles

Tags: openmaptiles

In openmaptiles schema I can't find about coastlines.
https://openmaptiles.org/schema/#water

I tried styling like this

```
{
  "id": "coastline",
  "type": "line",
  "source": "openmaptiles",
  "source-layer": "water",
  "paint": {
    "line-color": "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)"
  }
}
```

But like openmaptiles document says

> The polygons are split into many smaller polygons to improve rendering performance. This however can lead to less rendering options in clients since these boundaries show up. So you might not be able to use border styling for ocean water features.

I can't draw coastlines only.

Is there any way to draw coastlines?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is boundary what you're looking for?

```
  "id": "coastline",
  "type": "line",
  "metadata": {},
  "source": "openmaptiles",
  "source-layer": "boundary",
```